# Account & Block Polling not happening properly for the DApp in Trust Wallet Browser

Tags: wallets, metamask, drizzle

my DApp works fine in desktop/laptop using metamask which polls the accounts and blocks (1500ms and 3000ms respectively), as set in the drizzle options. But the same DApp when I open in trust wallet browser, the polling doesnt happen. Thus the values are not getting automatically updated and rendered as they change, in the DApp. Any suggestions as to the possible reasons? I'm using drizzle-react with latest context API, in my DApp.